# Apache Storm Bolt in C++

Tags: java, c++, apache, apache-storm, multilingual

I am a newbie at Apache Storm. I am trying to write bolts in c++. I referred to [this](http://demeter.inf.ed.ac.uk/cross/stormcpp.html) link and tried to run the WordCountTopology example. The splitsentence bolt is in cpp. But when I submit the jar on the cluster(local) I get the following error:

```
2016-12-15 20:22:16.911 o.a.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.

Serializer Exception:

```
at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:91) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:131) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__8058$fn__8071.invoke(executor.clj:795) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_121]
2016-12-15 20:22:16.912 o.a.s.d.executor [ERROR]
```

The only difference between my SentenceSplitTest.java and the one from the link is in the super() call:
Mine reads : `super("g++","SplitSentenceTest.cpp","Storm.cpp","jsoncpp.cpp");`

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.